# The dates changed after MySQL database get imported

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I just exported a MySQL database from our old server using:

```
mysqldump -u [uname] -p[pass] db_name > db_backup.sql
```

I then imported the database file `db_backup.sql` into our new server using phpMyAdmin:

```
PhpMyAdmin->Import->File to Import
```

**The dates in the new database tables are different.** Why have they changed and how can I stop this?

Here are the old database dates:
[image]

And here are the new database dates, why are they changing??
[image]

Comment: The servers are in different timezones, 6 hours apart it seems.

Comment: SET TIME_ZONE = '+00:00';

Comment: @vanloc Do you mean do this in my new server phpMyAdmin?

Comment: Your `time_zone` when export database? I think you should set timezone to UTC when importing data, not exporting. From documentation of '--tz-utc' option: "mysqldump sets its connection time zone to UTC and adds SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' to the dump file." So, the dump is in UTC. But since you use tab dumps, the "SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00" instruction is not executed, so you have to set the timezone on the connection manually. Command: `set time_zone=@old_time_zone`. Your server has `time_zone` different with your location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

Adding the `--skip-tz-utc` option to the export script.

**Solution 2:**

I think you should set timezone to UTC when importing data, not exporting.

From the documentation of `--tz-utc` option:

> "mysqldump sets its connection time zone to UTC and adds SET
>   TIME_ZONE='+00:00' to the dump file." So, the dump is in UTC. 
>   But since you use tab dumps, the "SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00" instruction is
>   not executed, so you have to set the timezone on the connection
>   manually.

Command: `set time_zone=@old_time_zone`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but maybe you have different time set on each of server. I see only days and hours have changed, so it's look like 18 hours. Check it out.

Change the global time_zone variable on the server:
`SET GLOBAL time_zone = 'America/Los_Angeles';`

UPDATE the data after the fact, applying MySQL's CONVERT_TZ() function:

```
UPDATE my_table
SET    my_column = CONVERT_TZ(
                     my_column,
                     'America/Los_Angeles',
                     'Australia/Adelaide'
                   );
```

Comment: is there a way to just have phpMyAdmin ignore this?